# update div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script. With that I am trying to update the div "right" in the jsp page. It's contained in a single file. It does not seem to update. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#right').load('score.jsp');

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#right').load('score.jsp');
    }, 10000);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="c2f2bd">
```

Updated

Moved to file score.jsp

```
        <img class="small" src="VTVFile1.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
        <img class="small" src="VTVFile2.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />

        <img class="small" src="VTVFile3.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
        <img class="small" src="VTVFile4.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
```

---

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to add the url of the content you want to load into the right div: `$('#right').load(url_of_content);` - see this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: what did you want  to load pass url of page with onload function like load("[url of page with onload function]");

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is just raising a `load` event on the `#right` div. If you want to load content then you need to specify the location to make the request to, eg:

```
$('#right').load('/foo/bar/content.php');
```

---

> It will now take X seconds before the content loads the first time. Is there a way to make the content visible on first load and then refresh at the interval ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right').load('/foo/bar/content.php'); // on load

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#right').load('/foo/bar/content.php'); // every 3 seconds
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: trying to load index2.jsp again will render the page twice.

Comment: Assuming that's the location of the containing page, then that's correct. You need to separate the content you want to load in to its own page.

Comment: ok, that seems to work. But one last problem remain. It will now take X seconds before the content loads the first time. Is there a way to make the content visible on first load and then refresh at the interval ?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: Does help with loading. But I now notice that the update every 10 seconds will not display any new information. Putting an alert there will show that the update is called. What am I missing? new code in question.

Comment: You'd need to check the network tab of the console for that to see why it's taking so long. I would suggest opening a new question about network performance issues though.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It does not render any new content at all no matter of time. It will just load the content the first time. Then no update will happen (though the call is made to the update function).

Comment: Check the console for an error. There's no reason it would work onload only.

Comment: Can't see anything in the console that should make this a problem. You can see the difference here http://scoring.megahooked.com/index2.jsp and http://scoring.megahooked.com (this is without the jquery stuff)

Comment: The point here is that the jpg files will be renewed every 15 seconds so I don't want to load the "old" jpgs but the new ones. Which is that I hope would happen on the refresh.

Comment: In that case you need to stop them being cached by appending a timestamp to the end of the url, eg `demo.jpg?2839283982`. The idea being that the value after `?` changes on each request

Comment: Does not make a difference. Do they need to be in a form tag?